# iOS 7.1 has more CoreImage filters than listed in docs (e.g. CIBumpDistortion and CIBumpDistortionLinear.) Can we use them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

Core image has a public API for interrogating it for a list of supported filters, and asking for the parameters used to control those filters.

If you interrogate iOS 7.1, the list of filters returned includes a number of filters that are not shown in the current Core image Filter Reference.

Specifically, I'm looking at CIBumpDistortion and CIBumpDistortionLinear. The Core image Filter Reference lists those filters, but it only lists them as available in Mac OS.

Ordinarily, I would think that the extra filters would be considered private to the Core Image Framework, and therefore unavailable. However, as mentioned above, public methods like filterNamesInCategory and filterNamesInCategories are listing the filter names, the attributes and inputKeys are listed, and the filters (mostly) work when called. There are a few bugs, but that's tangential to the question.

I posted this question to the Apple developer boards hoping somebody from Apple would give a definitive answer, but nobody has replied yet. What do people here think?

Comment: If they're there, you can use them. It's common to enumerate all installed filters and present them to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are listed in a query to `[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn]`, those CIFilters are safe to use. That's a publicly-available query, and shouldn't return any private Core Image filters.

This sounds like a case where the documentation hasn't quite caught up to what they've added, which I've seen with a couple of iOS updates. I might suggest filing a [documentation bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to request that this be brought in line. I've done that before and they did update the documentation to match.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in Brad. That was my understanding as well. I wish somebody from Apple would respond semi-officially to my query on the Apple iOS developer forums. BTW, you might want to take a look at this post on odd  behavior of some CI filters: [New CoreImage filters not working as expected](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/222739?tstart=0)

Comment: @DuncanC - Well, you know what I'd tell you to do: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . In all seriousness, the white you're seeing on the Gaussian blur is due to an extension of the blur as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20483704/19679 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910625/cigaussianblur-and-ciaffineclamp-on-ios-6 . It's extending the image border to account for the blur radius. Can't comment on the other two filters, but they might be experiencing something similar.